# jQuery select option, change html content. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I thought it would be as simple as this...

```
$('#yourSelect').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '12500', '8500', '7000') {
        $("#textBox").html("+ £10 delivery");
    } else {
        $("#textBox").html("+ £6 delivery");
    }
});
```

FRONT

```
<select name="Amount" id="yourSelect">
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="7000">7000</option>
    <option value="8500">8500</option>
    <option value="12500">12500</option>
</select>

<div id="textBox">+ £6 delivery</div>
```

have i lost my mind? whats wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `if ($(this).val() == '12500', '8500', '7000') {`you need to use the `||` operator:

```
$('#yourSelect').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == '12500' || value == '8500' || value == '7000') {
        $("#textBox").html("+ £10 delivery");
    }
    else {
        $("#textBox").html("+ £6 delivery");
    }
});​
```

As commented by *@hafichuk*, you can parse the value to a number and use a simpler condition:

```
if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) >= 7000)
    $("#textBox").html("+ £10 delivery");
else
    $("#textBox").html("+ £6 delivery");
```

You could make it even simpler with:

```
var output = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) >= 7000 ? '+ £10 delivery' 
                                                 : '+ £6 delivery';
$("#textBox").html(output);
```

Comment: One thing that *may* be more appropriate is to treat your "Amount" as a number instead of a string. I'd think about using a greater than comparison instead: `if (value >= 7000) {`

Comment: @hafichuk. Thanks, added that to my answer. Added credits. I wish we could  split the rep... **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

change the if condition

```
var val = $(this).val();
if (val == '12500' || val ==  '8500' || val ==  '7000')
```

otherway is

```
var arr = ['12500','8500','7000'];
$('#yourSelect').change(function () {
    if (arr.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1) {
        $("#textBox").html("+ £10 delivery");
    } else {
        $("#textBox").html("+ £6 delivery");
    }
});
```

Comment: better cache the jQuery object then construct it three times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the `if` is not a valid boolean expression. Change to this:

```
if ($(this).val() == '12500' ||  $(this).val() == '8500' || $(this).val() ==  '7000') {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourSelect').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '12500' || $(this).val() == '8500' || $(this).val() == '7000') {
            $("#textBox").html("+ £10 delivery");
        }
        else {
            $("#textBox").html("+ £6 delivery");
        }
    });
})​
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/F6eNY/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `$(this).val() >= 7000` if delivery always costs more when above a certain amount. Then you don't have to change the code when the amount choices change unless you're also changing the higher delivery cost threshold.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourSelect').change(function() {
    var deliveryPrice = parseInt(this.value, 10) >= 7000 ? 10 : 6;
    $('#textBox').text('+ £' + deliveryPrice + ' delivery');
});
```